# Kernel Erro: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: Anaconda New Environment Kernel Failure on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I set up a new conda environment and ran jupyter lab and notebook separately. No cigars.
Any hint on what might be the issue here?

Machine - Windows 10, Python 3.8 Anaconda from May 2021

What I've tried so far:

1. Install reinstall of Anaconda has not helped.
2. conda update conda
3. Made Sure the environment kernel is active
4. Made sure python 2.7 isn't hanging around

The Traceback is below.

> Blockquote
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704,
> in _execute
> result = await result
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
> model = yield maybe_future(
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
> value = future.result()
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
> kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
> value = future.result()
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
> yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
> kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
> value = future.result()
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
> kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
> km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 341, in start_kernel
> self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 249, in _launch_kernel
> return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 132, in launch_kernel
> proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BayesianBoy\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified